# Add button that will create new dropdown lists and remove the selected value from the new dpl

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, dropdown

I need to create an add button that every time the user presses it, a new dropdown list will be created and the selected value won't be in the new dpl. Also the first dropdown list is getting the data from the database(this is done).

I tried doing this [example][1] but it doesn't work! any tips?

Also, this is for practice so no need for validations etc etc.

**HTML CODE**

```
    <div id="services-D" class="oneField" >                 
                    <label id="services-L" for="services" class="label preField reqMark" style="width: 100px; min-width:0">Services</label><br>
                    <select id="c_service" name="c_service" class="required  dynamic-select" style="width:170px" >
                        <option value="">Select Service...</option>
                        <?php
                            $res=mysqli_query($dbc,"Select t1 t2 Where t4s = 'Y'");
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) { ?>
                            <option value = <?php echo $row['invoice_code']?> > <?php echo $row['t1'] . ": " . $row['t2'];}?> </option>
                        ?>
                    </select>

                </div>
<button type="button" id="btn_add_service"   style="">Add Service</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
$('#btn_add_service').on('click', function() {  
    selected = $('#c_service').prop('selectedIndex');
    if (selected != 0 && $('#c_service').find('option').length != 2){
    newselector = $('<select id="c_service"></select>').insertAfter('#c_service');
    $('#c_service').find('option').each(function(index,item) {
      if (index != selected){
        $(newselector).append(item);
      }
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: What `selected value`?  Please share some HTML, JavaScript to exemplify the issue.

Comment: check it now @AlanLarimer

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exacly what you are looking for, but I have tried to make it based on your description. Hope [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/ehorcbfq/3/) can help you out.

HTML:

```
<select onchange="NewSelection(this);">
  <option>Select an option</option>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
  <option>Option 4</option>
  <option>Option 5</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript / JQuery:

```
function NewSelection(selector){
    selected = $(selector).prop('selectedIndex');
    if (selected != 0 && $(selector).find('option').length != 2){
    newselector = $('<select onchange="NewSelection(this);"></select>').insertAfter(selector);
    $(selector).find('option').each(function(index,item) {
      if (index != selected){
        $(newselector).append(item);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks man! this one works just fine! I will just have to amend it so it will print one below the other!!!

Comment: actually using a button with this code complicates things a bit! it does show a new dpl list but just one..i edited my question if you can have a look